# Trying to hide the first and third column of ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a table that uses ng repeat for the columns, and now i want to hide the first and third column. Does anyone know how I would do that?

```
ng-hide="$first&&$third"
```

Didn't work

This is how it looks atm:

```
<th role="columnheader" ng-repeat="column in tableColumns" ng-hide="$first&&$third" ng-if="column.visible">{{column.displayName}}</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter for that. And check for the value of the counter to add a column. See this bellow code as a reference.

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in OrderList">
     <td>{{obj.ID}}</td>
     <td>{{obj.Name}}</td>
     <td ng-if="((++$index != 3)||($index != 1))">
         <i>Delete</i>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This hides any value at first and third position in an array

```
<span ng-hide="($index + 1) == ($first || ($first + 3))">{{val.CompID}}</span>
```